# Terminology: Smooth Representations of Locally Profinite Groups.

Tags: representation-theory, locally-compact-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a locally profinite group.

A smooth representation is a complex representation ($V,\rho$) of $G$  such that the stabiliser of any $v \in V$ is open.

One can show that (as $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a lie group and has NSS), a (finite dimensional) representation of $G$ is continuous if and only if $\ker(\rho)$ is open.

Therefore, in finite dimensions, continuous representations are smooth.

Furthermore, as
$$
\ker(\rho) = \cap_v \text{Stab}_G(v),
$$
and the intersection on the right can be taken as finite for finite dimensional $V$,
smooth also implies continuous. So these are equivalent for finite dimensions.

What about infinite dimensions? Does either imply the other?

What is the reason for this terminology? I only ask because I am conditioned to thinking that these implications must be smooth implies continuous, and not necessarily the other way around!

Comment: Be careful : your argument for the characterization of continuous maps out of $G$ doesn't work in infinite dimensions, because you're no longer working with $GL_n(\mathbb C)$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Ahhh yes, I'll edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose continuous here means the map $P:G \times V \rightarrow V$ is continuous, given V the discrete topology. Then smooth certainly implies continuous, literally by definition ( check the inverse image of a single vector under P is open)

But I don’t think the other side is right as it should depend on the group.

Comment: I think the converse holds clearly too. If $P$ is continuous, and the net $g_i$ tends to $1$ and $v$ is fixed, then $g_iv$ tends to $v$ in the discrete topology, i.e., equals $v$ for large $i$. That is, the stabilizer of $v$ is open. (For the initial direction: if stabilizers are open, $g_i\to g$, should imply $g_iv$ eventually equal to $gv$, and this holds: $g^{-1}g_i$ tends to 1; since stabilizers are open, eventually $g^{-1}g_iv=v$, so eventually $gv=g_iv$.)

Comment: No, by continuous here I mean as a function $G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbf{C})$. If $V$ is given the discrete topology the notion of continuous you give above is equivalent to smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Already $G=\mathbb Z_p$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb Z_p)$ by translation is continuous, but it is easy to make not-locally-constant functions in $L^2(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Also, it is misleading to say that smooth repn spaces "have no topology" or "have the discrete topology". Rather, they have the colimit topology from being expressed as the ascending union of their finite-dimensional subspaces. Yes, every linear map from such a space is continuous... which is why incorrect remarks about the topology do not lead directly to disaster. :)

So, in the best case, for every compact open $K$ in $G$, the subspace $V^K$ of $K$-fixed vectors is finite-dimensional, and $V=\bigcup V^K$. This is not so for $V=L^2(\mathbb Z_p)$, but *is* correct for $V$ the $K$-finite vectors. Things like that.

Comment: Could you please comment on how to construct such a $f\in L^2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ that is not locally constant ?

Comment: @rae306, well, $|x|_p$ is not locally constant near $0$, and we can add lots of translates to wreck local constancy throughout $\mathbb Z_p$, for example. But/and locally constant things are dense in $L^2$...